# How to index a table with order by?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Using a while loop I'm able to return my table in the order I want, but after implementing pagination the variable I've created (counter) resets itself on each page, frustratingly.  Example code:

```
$sql = ('SELECT id,name,logo FROM mytable ORDER BY name DESC LIMIT 25');
$query = mysqli_query($db_conx,$sql);
$counter = 0;

while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
    $counter++;
    echo "$counter, $row['id'], $row['name']";
    echo "<br />";
}
```

I've tried many things and can't get this to work.  Obviously my logic is flawed.  The loop returns the correct results, but the $counter variable breaks on each page, resetting itself indefinitely.

What I am trying to do is get $counter to increase by 25 (representing results for each page) for each of the pages created by the pagination loop.  Example code:

```
for ($i=1; $i<=$total_pages; $i++) {
    echo "<a href='page.php?page=".$i."'>&nbsp[".$i."]</a> ";
    $GLOBALS["counter"]+=25;            
};
```

Obviously this was not working, so I am stumped at what I should try next.  If anyone has any ideas I would love to hear them, I have heard great things about the SO community.

Comment: use limit and offset. `....LIMIT <offset>, <limit>`

Comment: Offset is the current page number -1 (assuming page number starts with 1) and lmit is the page size ( number of records per page)

Comment: But be aware of lack of descending indexes in MySQL.

Comment: @1000111 Can you leave a full answer?

Comment: Processing pagination requires two parameters (current page and page size). Are you passing those in the request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to display only the first 25 results at any time.

You need to initialize $counter to zero if it's the first page, to 26 if it's the second page, and so on :

```
$counter = 0;
if(isset($_GET['counter'])){
    $counter = intval($_GET['counter']);
}
```

You need to modify your query to fetch a different set of results for each page :

```
$sql = 'SELECT id,name,logo FROM mytable ORDER BY name DESC LIMIT ' . mysqli_real_escape_string($db_conx, $counter . ',25');
$query = mysqli_query($db_conx,$sql);
```

Then I assume you display a link to the other paginated pages, you need to pass it the value of $counter :

```
<a href="results.php?counter=<?php echo $counter;?>">Next</a>
```

Comment: This wasn't really the answer, but I left you without additional information.  Solved this by getting rid of $counter=0; and replacing it with $counter = ($pages-1) * 25